# In Pygame, I can only display text once I stop updating and drawing, why?

Tags: rendering, python, pygame, text

At this moment, I can only display text once I stop updating and drawing sprites. In the code below (which is actually the game loop), you can see how if `GAMEOVER == True` (gameloop stops drawing), the text "Game Over!" is displayed. But if I try to display any text while drawing and updating, it doesn't appears until I stop drawing the sprites. In fact, the frist block to display text ("My Game!") isn't shown, as I said, until the gameloop stops drawing. I need to display some info like, name of char, instructions, etc while the game is running, so, how can I render text in every loops and frames?

The game loop:

```
while True:

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 30)
    label = myfont.render("My Game!", 1, (255, 255, 0))
    SCREEN.blit(label, (500, 400))

    if PLAYER.healthBase <= 0:
        GAMEOVER = True #True para que se acabe la partida

    if not GAMEOVER:  
        charsGroup.update(time_passed)
        npcsGroup.update(time_passed)
        mapTilesGroup.draw(SCREEN)
        charsGroup.draw(SCREEN)
        npcsGroup.draw(SCREEN)
        drawBullets()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    time_passed = freq.tick(0) /1000.

    if GAMEOVER:
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 30)
        label = myfont.render("GAME OVER!", 1, (255, 255, 0))
        SCREEN.blit(label, (400, 300))


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the sprites drawing over the text?

Text isn't a special thing, it's just another sprite you render to the screen (albeit one you generate in a special way).

If you render the text and then at the same position render a sprite you won't see the text because there is something in front of it.

Render the texts *after* rendering the sprites.